# Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Reading Excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I am importing excel sheet into sql server database the excelsheet contains 3 columns id|data|passport I am using SqlBulkCopy

```
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString);

string[] filePaths = null;
string strFileType = null;
string strFileName = null;
string strNewPath = null;
int fileSize;
int flag=0;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}



protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    strFileType = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName).ToString().ToLower();
    strFileName = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName.ToString();
    FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Import/" + strFileName + strFileType));
    strNewPath = Server.MapPath("~/Import/" + strFileName + strFileType);
    fileSize = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength / 1024;

    //EXCEL DETAILS TABLE
    con.Open();
    //=========================================
    DataTable dt8 = new DataTable();
    SqlCommand cmd8 = new SqlCommand("insert into exceldetails (name,type,details,size)" + "values(@name,@type,@details,@size)", con);
    cmd8.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = strFileName;
    cmd8.Parameters.Add("@type", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = strFileType;
    cmd8.Parameters.Add("@details", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = DateTime.Now;
    cmd8.Parameters.Add("@size", SqlDbType.Int).Value = fileSize;
    cmd8.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    try
    {
        SqlDataAdapter da8 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd8);
        da8.Fill(dt8);
    }
    catch { }
    //=========================================

    //CHOOSING EXCEL CONNECTIONSTRING

    string excelConnectionString = "";
    switch (strFileType)
    {
        case ".xls":

            excelConnectionString = String.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" + "Data Source=" + strNewPath + "; Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;");
            break;
        case ".xlsx":
            {
                excelConnectionString = String.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + "Data Source=" + strNewPath + "; Extended Properties=Excel 12.0 Xml;");

                break;
            }
    }

    //===================================
    //PRE EXCEL COUNT

    // Create Connection to Excel Workbook
    using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("Select ID,Data,passport FROM [Sheet1$]", connection);
        OleDbCommand command1 = new OleDbCommand("select count(*) from [Sheet1$]", connection);

        //Sql Server Table DataTable
        DataTable dt4 = new DataTable();
        SqlCommand cmd4 = new SqlCommand("select * from excelsheet", con);
        try
        {
            SqlDataAdapter da4 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd4);
            da4.Fill(dt4);//sql table datatable
        }
        catch { }

        //===============================

        //excelsheet datatable
        DataTable oltlb = new DataTable();
        OleDbCommand olcmd = new OleDbCommand("select * from [Sheet1$]", connection);
        try
        {
            OleDbDataAdapter olda = new OleDbDataAdapter(olcmd);
            olda.Fill(oltlb); //excel table datatable
        }
        catch { }

        //==============================


        using (DbDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            // SQL Server Connection String
            string sqlConnectionString = "Data Source=DITSEC3;Initial Catalog=test;Integrated Security=True";

            con.Open();
            DataTable dt7 = new DataTable();
            dt7.Load(dr);
            DataRow[] ExcelRows = new DataRow[dt7.Rows.Count];
            DataColumn[] ExcelColumn = new DataColumn[dt7.Columns.Count];

            //=================================================
            for (int i1 = 0; i1 < ExcelRows.Length; i1++)
            {

                if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(ExcelRows[i1]["passport"].ToString()))
                {
                    ExcelRows[i1]["passport"]="0";

                }

                string a = Convert.ToString(ExcelRows[i1]["passport"]);
                char a1 = a[0];

                if (a1 >= 'A' || a1 <= 'Z')
                {
                    Label12.Text = "CAPITAL";
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    Label12.Text = "notgood";


                    flag = flag + 1;

                }

            }
            //=========================================================

            if (flag == 0)
            {
                using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConnectionString))
                {
                    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "ExcelTable";
                    dt7.Rows.CopyTo(ExcelRows, 0);

                    //==========================================================================================
                    for (int i = 0; i < ExcelRows.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if (ExcelRows[i]["passport"] == DBNull.Value)
                        {
                            ExcelRows[i]["passport"] = 0;
                        }

                    }
                    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(ExcelRows);
                    //==========================================================================================
                    for (int i = 0; i < ExcelRows.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if (ExcelRows[i]["data"] == DBNull.Value)
                        {
                            // Include any actions to perform if there is no date
                            //ExcelRows[i]["data"] = Convert.ToDateTime("0");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            DateTime oldDate = Convert.ToDateTime(ExcelRows[i]["data"]).Date;
                            DateTime newDate = Convert.ToDateTime(oldDate).Date;
                            ExcelRows[i]["data"] = newDate.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
                        }

                    }

                    //==========================================================================================
                }
                //======

            }
            else
            {
                Label13.Text = "Wrong Format";
            }
        }

    }
}
}
```

> ERROR AT : string a = ExcelRows[i1]["passport"].ToString();
>   ERROR: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

also notice that when i run this after removing passport comparison the first row goes null in the database.

Comment: First problem: `catch { }` can *very* easily be masking errors. **Never** have empty catches that don't even log.

Comment: Make sure you have a column name "passport", there could be multiple things which can be null, ExcelRows itself, or the `i1` row is null or the column "passport" doesn't exist

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at this code:

```
    DataRow[] ExcelRows = new DataRow[dt7.Rows.Count];
    DataColumn[] ExcelColumn = new DataColumn[dt7.Columns.Count];

    for (int i1 = 0; i1 < ExcelRows.Length; i1++)
    {
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(ExcelRows[i1]["passport"].ToString()))
```

You haven't *populated* `ExcelRows` at all. You've created an array where every element is null. So of *course* `ExcelRows[0]["passport"]` will throw an exception.

Why aren't you using `dt7.Rows` to get the data?

Additionally:

- This code shouldn't be in your presentation layer to start with
- Avoid empty catch blocks
- Try to refactor your code into smaller methods
- Use a consistent naming style, ideally using `camelCase` for variable names
- Give variables more meaningful names - what does `dt7` really *mean* to you?
- Use `using` statements for connections, commands etc

Comment: Well i am a newbie so yes i admit my coding skills are pathetic at the moment. How should i dt7 as you suggested , can you write some code?

Comment: @Arbaaz: Well it's hard to advise without knowing what you're trying to achieve, but you should probably be using `dt7.Rows[i1]` instead of `ExcelRows[i1]`.

Comment: yup i did what you advised but now the error is at 
if (a[0]>= 'A' && a[0] <= 'Z' && a[0] !='0' )
error: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Comment: @Arbaaz: Then that suggests you've got an empty string - as you should be able to tell in the debugger. But Stack Overflow isn't a web-based interactive debugging tool - I'm not going to go through every problem in your code, one by one. You should work through as much as you can yourself, and then if you have another *specific* question, ask it as a separate SO question (indicating what you've tried etc).